# How to retrieve a single contact

Tags: android, contacts, provider, contactscontract

how can I retrieve a single contact and some associated data (e.g. emails, phonenumbers, addresses...) by its id/lookupkey?

This is the code I use to add contacts (actually its from the internet and is working for me).

```
// Asking the Contact provider to create a new contact
    try {
        result = this.context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(
                ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "Exception: " + e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    Uri myContactUri = result[0].uri;
    int lastSlash = myContactUri.toString().lastIndexOf("/");
    int length = myContactUri.toString().length();
    int contactID = Integer.parseInt((String) myContactUri.toString()
            .subSequence(lastSlash + 1, length));

    return contactID;
```

Now I want to fetch this new contact. How do I do it? All I came up with is this:

```
    ContentResolver content = context.getContentResolver();

    String[] projection = { Data.LOOKUP_KEY, Data.MIMETYPE,
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS };

    // Defines the selection clause
    String selection = Data.LOOKUP_KEY + " = ?";

    // Defines the sort order
    String sortOrder = Data.LOOKUP_KEY;

    String[] args = {"2400"};

    Cursor cursor = content.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection,
            args, sortOrder);
```

When I remove the selection I get all contacts+all their data. So I looked up the key 2400 in my case and wanted to fetch this contact by its lookupkey. Well, does not work. cursor.getCount() return 0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution now is to use to following:

```
    String[] projection = { Data.MIMETYPE,
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS };

    // Defines the selection clause
    String selection = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=?";

    // Defines the sort order
    String sortOrder = Data.LOOKUP_KEY;

    String[] args = { id+"" };

    Cursor cursor = content.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection,
            args, sortOrder);
```

Sort order doesnt matter, but I use the RAW_CONTACT_ID, which works well!